# How to programmatically rename fields in Tableau Desktop (e.g. Python)?

Tags: python, automation, tableau-api

I have a huge data source with 500+ fields, and would like to rename them based on a mapping table I have (in Excel). Is it possible to do this programmatically (e.g. via Python) on my Tableau Desktop?

Tableau offers a couple of Python packages like
Tableau Server Client (TSC); tabcmd;
But they are meant for the server, and provide limited capabilities.

Comment: What about gui based recorded commands?

Comment: maybe. check out http://ugamarkj.blogspot.com/2017/03/automated-data-lineage-documentation.html?q=python

Comment: You can save a Tableau data source as an XML file with the extension (TDS). The menu command is called “Add to Saved Data Sources”. If the TSC library or the Tableau Document API don’t give you the features you need, you could look at ways to revise the XML in the TDS file. Its pretty self-explanatory, just save a backup first.

Comment: Thanks @Igrecolla. Do you have any to recommend. Was thinking of `pyautogui` ( screenshot -> check for value -> infer column name -> look up mapping and rename -> etc.) But the workflow seems complex and is likely not a robust soln.

Comment: Thanks @Bernardo. I browsed through, think it is more for Tableau server. There's no `tableauServerAddress` etc. for Tableau desktop, as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks @AlexBlakemore. That is indeed quite promising. Will explore it next time :)

Answer (score 1):

it can be done with an excel that has a mapping (previous name - new name)

but first, you need to convert your Tableau XML to a dataframe (a table of sorts basically) with the fields you need to change, you can do it through:
the ElementTree package, you will need to loop through the xml and search what you need (inside the xml: caption = name in tableau).

After you have your fields in the df you can join it with the excel file and reassign names, specifically the "caption" is what you're looking for.

If you need any clarifications let me know.