# How to Create Name Labels and Map Them to Data Source Items in Tableau Desktop?

Tags: mapping, tableau-desktop

I have a list of locale names for the languages being used in the reports. Without making any changes in the Excel or the Data Source, can I create a new set of language names that are more user friendly for non-technical, business people who will be using the reports?

[image: Data Reports Language Names]

To explain this further, I would like the names under `Target Language` to be displayed as `Arabic`, `Czech`, `German`, `English`, etc.

The card/filter is used in more than one worksheet, so I'd like to have a global option to apply wherever needed. (I've deleted the other fields/table names for privacy reasons)

I already tried googling and checking Tableau Help Center, and also [this other post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64202440/how-to-programmatically-rename-fields-in-tableau-desktop-e-g-python), but those don't really answer my question and I'm still not clear on how to do this.

Comment: I am not sure, i fully understand, do you want to "Group" the languages in Tableau ?

Comment: @MKD no, see the right pane, `ar_AA`, `cs_CZ`, `de_DE`, ...? Those are the locale names. I want to display the full language names instead. So `ar_AA` would be displayed as `Arabic`, `cs_CZ` would be displayed as `Czech`, and so on. And I want to do this in Tableau without tweaking anything in Excel.

Comment: Then, I suggest you use "Alias" option in Tableau

Comment: Can you please mark the Answer I posted below as solved so that we can help everyone